# How can i get bank information from source?

Tags: stripe-payments, plaid

I have liked a online bank with plaid API to stripe. i have created a stripe customer with source bank token. But later I couldn't get bank information from source. It is showing

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest

Message: No such source: btok_1BOiMhGnklINT0gr7TYCRuvO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means that the API key you used to make the second API call is not from the Stripe account you linked to your Plaid account and also not the same you used when creating the customer. I'd recommend checking the API keys in both of your scripts.

Also once you fix this part, you should not reuse the token in subsequent calls as it would have been consumed by the customer creation call. You need to use the bank account id that was created instead (ba_xxx).